# align-Items для CSS

Tags: css

Всем привет, я правильно понимаю, что при использовании `align-items`, если высота главного блока не указана, то элементы выравниваются по самому высокому блоку, а если указана, то они выравниваются по нижней/верхней и т. д. линиям основного блока?

Answer (score 1):

Если высота главного блока не указана, то она равняется высоте самого высокого дочернего блока. `align-items` работают все так же по отношению к главному блоку.

Answer (score 0):

Вы прав в случае, когда высота главного блока указана.

В случае, когда она не указана, вы тоже думаете правильно - я хочу только уточнить, что тогда *высота главного блока* определяется высотой самого высокого блока. Затем идет всё как в случае указанной высоты блока.